# Current SQL Server performance of IN vs EXIST for a complex static select

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, exists, sql-server-2016

I would like to know if IN will cache the result of a static complex query or will it executed for each row?

SAMPLE

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM customer a
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT b.customerId 
               FROM orders b 
               JOIN aricle c ON c.orderId = b.id 
               WHERE b.date = '20160910' and c.costcenter > 1000)
```

Now, will the result of the subquery temporally stored or would an `EXIST` be faster for this?

Let's assume the result are only a few rows < 100 but the query can be much more complex!

I know in that case I could also JOIN the tables but that's not the point.

I am especially interested in the behavior of current SQL Server

Thanks everybody :)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are asking. Can you please clarify what it is you are looking for?

Comment: I believe an IN would be faster because SQL Server is looking for a set of values as opposed to EXIST where it will have to look for each to exist before grabbing each value. With this query though neither would be too taxing of an operation.

Comment: basically, `in` works slower then `exists` when there is a large set of data to test. if you are talking about 100 rows there should be no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are specifically interested in behavior of SQR, then you can verify and see if the data was read from memory or from disk by running following command before your SQL statement.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
```

It will return the logical and physical reads.

Logical Reads:
Logical read indicates total number of data pages needed to be accessed from data cache to process query. It is very possible that logical read will access same data pages many times, so count of logical read value may be higher than actual number of pages in a table. Usually the best way to reduce logical read is to apply correct index or to rewrite the query.

Physical Reads 
Physical read indicates total number of data pages that are read from disk. In case no data in data cache, the physical read will be equal to number of logical read. And usually it happens for first query request. And for subsequent same query request the number will be substantially decreased because the data pages have been in data cache.

To compare between two queries, you can use execution plan to check the execution time and compare the queries.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I have to accept, that there is no absolute answer.